# How to sort result by owner ID SQL, Seqelize?

Tags: sql, orm, sequelize.js

**Please note the below contents:**

1. user table
2. where condition 1

1 **USER TABLE**

```
id owneeId  delete shop

1   12       1       1
2   13       1       1
3   7        1       1
4   7        1       1
```

2 **Where condition 1 of sequelize :**

```
const result = await findAllusers({
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [{
                owner_id: {
                    [Op.in]: rows.map(['12','13']),
                }
            }, {
                owner_id: {
                    [Op.notIn]: rows.map(['12','13']),
                },
             shop: 1
            }]
        }
```

**Desired Result :**

I need result as :

```
result =   [{id:1,ownerid:7,delete:1,shop:1},
{id:2,ownerid:7,delete:1,shop:1},
{id:3,ownerid:12,delete:1,shop:1},
{id:4,ownerid:13,delete:1,shop:1}]
```

the ownerid 7 peoples first ... then all other users.. but I am now getting result not sorted like that, and sometimes I am getting ownerid 7 perosna as last elements.

Comment: Do you want a SQL or sequelize answer?

Comment: @jarlh sequelize answer please, I will edit out SQL part. I think i am consuming people who want to help. Thank you

Comment: Please show SQL with desired sorting

Comment: @Anatoly (
    select *
    from users
    where ownerId = 7 and shop = 1
)
union
(
    select *
    from users 
    WHERE (ownerId in ('12', '13') and `delete` is null)  or    
        (ownerId not IN ('12','13')  and shop = 1 and `delete` is null)
); This is the sql . Here I need to get owner id 7 persons first ,then the rest of the persons...that means only after getting all owner id 7 person.. i need the rest to add to the result. Thank you

Comment: But if you don't limit a number of records you will get all uses that satisfy your conditions and you will be able to get all users with a given id from returned records.